# change view controller from right to left (Hebrew),

Tags: ios, objective-c

change view controller in storyboard from right to left (Hebrew),
I use the library(TKCalendarDayView) inside the viewcintrooler,

Answer (score 1):

change right to left to all app:

```
navigationBarAppearace.semanticContentAttribute = "if check language"
    ? .forceRightToLeft
    : .forceLeftToRight
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :
Note that in custom Transition, animated property does not matter so you can either set true or false.

```
CATransition *transition = [[CATransition alloc] init];
transition.duration = 0.5;
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
[self.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
[self presentViewController:yourViewController animated:false completion:nil];
```

Let me know if you face any trouble with this.

Comment: What a dashboardWorkout?

Comment: That will be your viewcontroller object to which you need to present.

Comment: this is not work to my view controller(maybe the library problem).

Comment: Hmm, can you post your code snippet here so I can get a better understanding?